# How can we configure the Bitnami Joomla stack to open a socket on startup?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, php-fpm, fastcgi, socket

I have deployed the Bitnami Ubuntu Joomla! 3.1.5-2 (64-bit) stack on Amazon Cloud:
http://bitnami.com/stack/joomla/cloud/amazon

By default, the stack is configured to run PHP using PHP-FPM. I have no problem getting the Joomla and phpmyadmin running as virtual hosts on Apache.

But now, I would like to add another virtual host. The problem I am having is, I have no idea how to get the system creating a socket on startup in the following folder:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-15-99:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 20:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct  9 15:39 ..
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Nov  3 20:43 joomla.sock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4 Nov  3 20:43 php5-fpm.pid
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Nov  3 20:43 phpmyadmin.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Nov  3 20:43 www.sock
bitnami@ip-172-31-15-99:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run$
```

I have the following `/opt/bitnami/apps/mywebsite/conf/php-fpm/pool.conf` file:

```
[mywebsite]
listen=/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/mywebsite.sock
include=/opt/bitnami/php/etc/common-dynamic.conf
include=/opt/bitnami/apps/mywebsite/conf/php-fpm/php-settings.conf
pm=dynamic
```

As it can be seen, `listen` points to the `mywebsite.sock` which does not currently exist.

I did an experiment, by removing the .sock files in the `/opt/bitnami/php/var/run` folder and they would come back on reboot.

So how can we configure it to open a socket for `mywebsite` on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully solved the problem by adding the following line at the bottom of `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.conf`:

```
include=/opt/bitnami/apps/mywebsite/conf/php-fpm/pool.conf
```

This line essentially takes the configuration defined in the `pool.conf` into account when PHP-FPM initiates itself.